# Python creating a dictionary from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOzXX.png)

I would like to convert it into a dictionary where the 'Keys' and 'Atom_Vals' columns are the key and values, respectively. I tried using `df.to_dict('dict')`, but what I got was a dictionary nested within a dictionary, which looks something like this:

```
{'Atom_Vals': {1: 'O14',
  2: 'C76',
  3: 'H108',
  4: 'C72', ...}
```

However, what I really want is something like this:

```
{1: 'O14',
  2: 'C76',
  3: 'H108',
  4: 'C72',...}
```

May I know if there is anything I can do to rectify this? Thank you!

Comment: Use `to_dict` on the column: `df.Atom_vals.to_dict()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't the whole df as a dict, only one column (a `Series`), so do

```
df.Atom_Vals.to_dict()
```

Use that notation in case the column name has space for example

```
df['Atom_Vals'].to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of dict['Atom_vals'] is a dictionary too, I believe that u could also just build the dataframe from:

```
df = pd.Dataframe(dict['Atom_vals'])
```

Comment: That isn't the question at all, please read again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for that particular column you want to convert.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"keys":[1,2,3,4,5],
"Atom_vals":["A12","B11","C23","Q564","T34"]})
print(df)

di=df["Atom_vals"].to_dict()
print(di)
```

This will give result :

```
{0: 'A12', 1: 'B11', 2: 'C23', 3: 'Q564', 4: 'T34'}
```

And as per the result you want, it might take more time, since the below way is an iterative way, where it will go through each value of that column with help of [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
res = {x+1 : df.iloc[x,1] for x in range(len(df["Atom_vals"]))}
print(res)
```

and this will give result :

```
{1: 'A12', 2: 'B11', 3: 'C23', 4: 'Q564', 5: 'T34'}
```